# send mail form feedback form from address not working in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, email

am trying feedback form so that user sends feedback message in mail.here is the code in jsp which sends mail to recepient for now am trying with static address.But I want the user address(from address).

```
       <%@ page language="java" 
        contentType="text/html; 
        charset=windows-1256"
         pageEncoding="windows-1256"         
         import="java.net.UnknownHostException"         
    %> 
    <%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
    <%@ page import="java.util.Date"%>
    <%@ page import="java.util.Random"%>
    <%@ page import="java.util.*, javax.mail.*, javax.mail.internet.*" %>

      <%           

        try{
        String report = request.getParameter("report"); 
        String qus = request.getParameter("qus"); 
        String category = request.getParameter("category"); 
        String email="something@gmail.com";
        String messageText = "feedback message sample";

     String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
     String user = "abc@gmail.com"; //Enter some valid gmail Id for verification
     String pass = "*******";                  // Enter password here
     String from = "fromaddress@gmail.com"; 
     String subject = "Report of Error"; 

     boolean sessionDebug = false; 

     Properties props = System.getProperties(); 
     props.put("mail.smtp.host", host); 
     props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
     props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 

    Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null); 
    mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug); 

    Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    InternetAddress fromaddress = new InternetAddress(from); 
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));


     InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(email)}; 
     msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address); 
     msg.setSubject(subject);
     msg.setText(messageText);
     msg.saveChanges();
    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtps");
    transport.connect(host, user, pass); 
    transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
           out.println(e);
        } 
    %>
```

The mail has been sent but it's going from abc@gmail.com but not from "fromaddress@gmail.com" I tried msg.setFrom() but that's not working.I want the mail to be sent from "fromaddress@gmail.com" not from authenticated id.Please let me know how to solve this.

Comment: `transport.connect(host, user, pass);`? you are using `abc@gmail.com`

Comment: gmail will only work with proper credentials.  Do the machine itself or your ISP have a running mail server?  If so, use that.

Comment: in the feedback form I will take email id and redirect to jsp page so that I need that mailid

Comment: with that mail id you can't sent any mail in java means with from id. its possible in php. in java we can send a mail with authentication only. @gowriP